# How to create a .NET Core app where user input is store in a file in json format through middleware

Tags: c#, .net-core

It should have two controllers with one middleware.

I'm encountering an issue with my API when making a POST request. The server is responding with the following error message:

```
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "00-2bc115df5ed0858eec53195b7ab19c57-e36dc0e44d06d4b9-00",
  "errors": {
    "$": [
      "The input does not contain any JSON tokens. Expected the input to start with a valid JSON token, when isFinalBlock is true. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0."
    ],
    "input": [
      "The input field is required."
    ]
  }
}
```

I've double-checked my request, and I'm certain that the JSON data is valid and that I've included the required fields. I've also set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json`. What could be causing this error?

I'm using [mention the programming language or framework you're working with] to send the request. Could there be any server-side issues causing this error?

Has anyone else encountered a similar issue, and what steps can I take to diagnose and resolve it?

In middleware:

```
public Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    if (context.Request.Method == "POST")
    {
        string requestBody;

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(context.Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            requestBody = reader.ReadToEndAsync().ToString();
        }

        SaveToJsonFile(requestBody);
    }

    return _next(context);
}

private void SaveToJsonFile(string data)
{
    try
    {
        List<object> existingData = new List<object>();

        if (File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            var jsonData = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
            existingData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<object>>(jsonData);
        }

        var newData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(data);
        existingData.Add(newData);

        File.WriteAllText(filePath, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(existingData, Formatting.Indented));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error saving data: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're using _"[mention the programming language or framework you're working with]"_ to send the request? :o Really?

Comment: Do you have a sample of the request you're sending?

Comment: You have middleware intercepting every POST for every endpoint, but you're still calling `_next`? Is the error being thrown by other middleware in the pipeline?